# Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset WordPress 4.8.1

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting a Warning:

> Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in
>   /homepages/27/d653904259/htdocs/clickandbuilds/wp-inc‌​ludes/class.wp-scrip‌​ts.php
>   on line 447

```
$l10n[$key] = html_entity_decode( (string) $value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); – j
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check inline; is `$value` set or not:

```
  $l10n[$key] = html_entity_decode( (isset($value)) ? $value : 'default text or html here...', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```